# MySQL cant join against temp table

Tags: mysql

Why can I not create a temporary table then immediately JOIN against it?

```
mysql> CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 as (select in_reply_to_id, COUNT(in_reply_to_id) as C from mentions where in_reply_to_id>0 group by in_reply_to_id);
```

> > Query OK, 57149 rows affected (0.14 sec)
> >     Records: 57149  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

```
mysql> select T.tweet_id, T.favorite_count, T.retweet_count, T2.C from 
-> tweets AS T JOIN table2 AS T2 
-> on T.tweet_id = T2.in_reply_to_id;
```

> > ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'twitter_analysis.table2 as' doesn't exist
> >     mysql>

But it **does** exist because I can select from it!

```
select count(*) from table2;
```

> > 57149 1 row in set (0.01 sec)

This error is extremely frustrating. 
Is there a way to put this temp table into the select query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can just put it in the query like this

```
select T.tweet_id, T.favorite_count, T.retweet_count, T2.C 
FROM tweets T 
JOIN 
(   SELECT in_reply_to_id, COUNT(in_reply_to_id) as C 
    FROM mentions 
    WHERE in_reply_to_id>0 
    GROUP BY in_reply_to_id
) T2 on T.tweet_id = T2.in_reply_to_id;
```

you could try selecting from the temporary table and joining the other table to it.

Comment: @Tommy sure thing! glad I could help :) did you try selecting from the temporary table and joining tweets table to it? that may be a workaround to what you were trying

Answer (score 1):

You could put them in one single query:

```
select T.tweet_id, T.favorite_count, T.retweet_count, T2.C from 
tweets T JOIN (select in_reply_to_id, COUNT(in_reply_to_id) as C from mentions where in_reply_to_id>0 group by in_reply_to_id) T2 
on T.tweet_id = T2.in_reply_to_id;
```